# How to determine multipart/form-data filetypes using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the [Griddler](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler) gem in a Rails 3.2 app to handle incoming emails with attachments.

The documentation indicates that attached files are multipart/form-data files.

Is there an easy ruby way to interrogate these files and determine their filetype? I need to handle different filetypes using different methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) under section 5 'Uploading Files'

> The object in the params hash is an instance of a subclass of IO.
>   Depending on the size of the uploaded file it may in fact be a
>   StringIO or an instance of File backed by a temporary file. In both
>   cases the object will have an original_filename attribute containing
>   the name the file had on the user’s computer and a content_type
>   attribute containing the MIME type of the uploaded file.

so you could interrogate `uploaded_io.content_type` and use different methods to work with whatever `content_type` is.

Hope this gets you started in the right direction

Comment: no problem, went through this myself a few months ago. glad I could help.